# Show desktop notifications for every new message in chats

Tags: feature-request, chat

I can enable desktop notifications for chats on the lower right side:

[image]

But I only get these notifications when I am pinged in a message like:

> @Lino bla bla bla - User

There is already a feature to play a notification sound for different kind of messages:

[image]

Could we also have the same options for desktop notifications? So that I could get desktop notifications for every new message in every chat I am currently part of?

---

Note: this is not related to the *SO Close Vote Reviewers*-Chat, I just chose it as an example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd like to see this feature as well, mainly to keep track on some specific chat rooms.

While there's currently no SE-sided support, I created a userscript as a workaround. It adds a link (as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyQ0x.png)), which toggles it for each room. It hooks into the SE chat API using `CHAT.addEventHandlerHook` to grab chat messages, and from there uses `Notification` to send you a notification, assuming the message isn't from you.

You can check if your browser supports the feature [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=Notification). If you aren't familiar with userscripts, you need a browser plugin for it. One example is TamperMonkey, but there's also other variants out there.

[Direct install](https://github.com/LunarWatcher/userscripts/raw/master/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere.user.js)

Code (also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/LunarWatcher/userscripts/blob/master/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere.user.js)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Desktop Notifications Everywhere
// @match        *://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match        *://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @downloadURL  https://github.com/LunarWatcher/userscripts/raw/master/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere.user.js
// @updateURL    https://github.com/LunarWatcher/userscripts/raw/master/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere/DesktopNotificationsEverywhere.meta.js
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

var url = null;
var uid = 0;
var room = "";
var toggled = false;

function load() {
    var value = GM_getValue("room-" + room);
    if (value == null) return false;
    else return value == "true" || value == "1";
}

function save() {
    GM_setValue("room-" + room, toggled);

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Parse various necessary data
    url = window.location.href;
    let i = $("#active-user").attr("class");
    uid = parseInt(i.replace("user-container user-", ""), 10);
    if (uid == 0) throw "Failed to find UID";

    room = $("#roomname").text();

    // Link the event handler
    CHAT.addEventHandlerHook(chatMessageRecieved);

    toggled = load();

    // Link toggler

     $("#sidebar-menu").append("| <a id='toggleAllNotifications' href='#' onclick='return false'>" + (toggled ? "Disable" : "Enable") + " all notifications</a>");


    $("#toggleAllNotifications").click(function () {
        toggleNotifications();
    });
});

function toggleNotifications() {
    toggled = !toggled;
    $("#toggleAllNotifications").text((toggled ? "Disable" : "Enable") + " all notifications");
    save();
}

function chatMessageRecieved({event_type, user_id, content, user_name}) {

    if(!toggled) return;
    if (event_type !== 1) {
        return false;
    }

    if(user_id == uid) return; // Ignore your own messages
    var text = $('<div>').html(content).text();
    if (text == "" || text == null) text = "<Image>"
    notify(text, user_name);

}


function notify(content, username) {

    if (Notification.permission !== 'granted')
        Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
        var notification = new Notification(room + " | " + username, {
            icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
            body: content
        });

        notification.onclick = function () {
            window.open(url);
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: is it required to have SO open in a tag for this to work? Or will it work even when only my browser is open?

Comment: It only works while a chat tab is open. It's a limitation of the API that can't be fixed.

Comment: I have a suggestion.. clicking on the notification opens the chat in a new tab... Instead of this if it would be great if it can bring the previously opened tab into focus... That way I won't have multiple tabs opened of the same chat... Great script btw I am loving it! :)