# "Follow" for chats

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Can we get "follow" functionality for chats, so we get notified about new messages even after we closed the tab? It's super useful for questions/answers. But with chats, I have to actively check over and over again or tell people they need to manually notify me (and hope they won't forget).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385123/show-desktop-notifications-for-every-new-message-in-chats

Comment: @SamuelLiew Seems related but not quite the same. I don't want desktop notifications (I'm using a phone, and my browser doesn't even allow them). I'd like the notifications to appear in the notifications on top of the page along with the others just like for followed questions/answers or like when someone does notify me from chat with `@`.

Comment: I just keep a tab open, honestly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Me, too, and I hate it. Don't you? How long do you keep it open? The full week until the room gets closed so you can be sure there won't be further responses?

Comment: Oh, I'm only in permanent chat rooms. Trying to "move the discussion to chat" rarely works out.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah I don't have an issue with "permanent" ones like the Python room. This is mostly about those chats started under answers/questions.

Comment: Quoting a response from a CM about `feature-request` on [meta-tag:chat]: "To be very candid, making feature requests for Chat is pretty futile at this time. There is already a list ten miles long, and I imagine [...] many [features] to make Chat mobile-friendly are already on it."